# Why can't I open files and locations across a home network?

Tags: 11.04, permissions, networking, home-directory, files

I have figured out how to get my two Ubuntu 11.04 machines to see each other, and I can look through shared files but when I go to open say a song in a shared music file I get an error message saying

> could not open location, you might not have permission to open the file.

I have set the file permissions to let it be both read and write. But it still will not let me listen to the song.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check Folder sharing options - right-click on shared folder and choose Properties-->Share. The section "Allow others to create and delete files in this folder" has to be checked.

[Here](http://www.jonathanmoeller.com/screed/?p=2941) you can find useful info how to setup samba on Ubuntu 11.04

[image: Folder share options]
[image: Permitions]